# Understanding conditional jumps

Tags: assembly, x86

```
[org 100h]

jmp start

start:
MOV AL, 5
MOV BL, 0xFF
CMP AL, BL
JG L1
MOV AX, 0
JMP Exit
L1:
MOV AX, 1
Exit:

mov ax,0x4c00
int 21h
```

Why does this jump to L1 after JG? As here al < bl and it should only jump to L1 if al > bl.

Am I right though?

The end result in ax should be 0 but it is giving 1. I'm using dosbox 0.74 and I'm a beginner in assembly.

Comment: `5 > -1`, so `al` is greater. Why do you think it's less/equal? ( http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html  .. the `cmp` instruction will set flags in a way that mnemonics like `jg = jump if greater` and `ja = jump if above` work as expected ... (when you understand the basic data types and why 8 bit `-1` is encoded as 1111_1111 in binary, i.e. 0xFF) ... for SIGNED integers in 8 bits you have working range -128..+127 .. for unsigned integers the range is 0..255 (you are loading `bl` with bit pattern "1111_1111" which can be interpreted as 255 (unint8) or -1 (int8) or anything (anything_t).

Comment: is it not 5 > 255 :@ what is wrong with me...
how can i make bl 255?
changing jg to ja does that?

Comment: 0xff *is* -1 in 8-bit 2's complement.

Comment: For 5 > 255 test you have to either use 16 bit registers (working range -32768..+32767, so +255 fits into 16 bits well), or unsigned interpretation of `cmp` result, i.e. `ja L1` instead of `jg` ...

Comment: wow bro thanks <3
now i need some reference when it is best explained which jumps consider what values

Comment: there used to be "documentation" on stackoverflow, where this particular topic was IMO described quite nicely, but it doesn't exist any more (and I'm too lazy to check webarchive, if it landed there), but in short, two things: 1) the jumps test only the flags (unless specified otherwise like `jcxz`), they are not aware of your intention or which instruction did set flags, so `jb` "jump bellow" will jump whenever CF=1, even if that CF was set by something what human would not interpret as "below" in that context (use then `jc` maybe in source, it's alias to make source easier to read).

Comment: 2) in that shortened [Intel manual (link)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html), the unsigned-related jumps are `ja/jb/...` ("below/above"), signed-related jumps are `jg/jl/...` ("greater/less"). But keep in mind they actually don't care about their name, they just check current flag status, set up by whatever last instruction(s)... Also don't assume much about flags being set by instructions, most of the time the arithmetic instructions set them as expected, but there are exceptions, like `dec/inc` does NOT modify CF (for good reasons, but it may surprise you) - so check inst. guide.

Comment: Got it Thanks <3

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Ped7D should have posted the answer as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @AlexD there must be some duplicate for this... actually I don't think these trivial-like questions are good fit for SO, to write somewhat meaningful bad assembly code one has to have at least some basics, one SO answer can't replace proper book/tutorial/lector. Also people asking similar question usually don't search old questions thoroughly, while proper canonical answer addressing this from all sides and explaining all the basic concepts of computing would be probably close to whole chapter of book... And that's what OP needs, a good book + lot of time... This Q+A is just temporary patch.